# Styles in vaadin not fine in Table inside Liferay Theme

Tags: liferay, themes, html-table, vaadin

We are using Vaadin 7.3.10 and we are developing a porlet 2.0 in eclipse. This porlet is deploying in Liferay 6.2-CE-ga3. We create a Liferay Theme (we extend of classic parent theme) and in this Theme we include the Vaadin Valo Theme. 
The problem is (ONLY IN FIREFOX) when we show one table and the heather td have a different size of the several rows td.

---

This is the HTML code generated in Vaadin:

```html
<div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_751" class="v-slot v-slot-tablaNueva">
   <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_750" style="width: 712px; height: 230px;" class="v-table v-widget v-has-width v-has-height tablaNueva v-table-tablaNueva">
      <div style="width: 710px;" class="v-table-header-wrap">
         <div class="v-table-header" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="width: 900000px;">
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width: 326px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 317px;">Nombre del seguro</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 95px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 86px;">Descuento</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 88px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 79px;">Campaña</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 100px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 91px;">Edad Aseg.</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 191px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 182px;">Capital Asegurado</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 101px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 92px;">Contratable</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 106px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 97px;">Documentos</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="v-table-column-selector" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_749" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; height: 190px; width: 710px;" class="v-scrollable v-table-body-wrapper v-table-body" tabindex="-1">
         <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_748" style="height: 113px;">
            <div style="height: 0px;" class="v-table-row-spacer"></div>
            <table id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_747" class="v-table-table">
               <tbody id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_746">
                  <tr id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_745" class="v-table-row" style="">
                     <td id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_744" style="width: 325px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_743" style="text-align: left; width: 325px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">Seguro de protección familiar en femenino</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 94px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 94px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">No</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 87px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 87px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">No</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 99px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 99px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">18 - 64</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 190px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">40000.0 - 450000.0</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 100px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">SI</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 105px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 105px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">+Info</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_801" class="v-table-row-odd v-selected" style="">
                     <td style="width: 325px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 325px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">Seguro de protección familiar</div>
                     </td>
                     <td id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_800" style="width: 94px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div id="yui_patched_v3_11_0_1_1423812986764_799" style="text-align: left; width: 94px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">No</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 87px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 87px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">No</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 99px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 99px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">18 - 64</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 190px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">40000.0 - 250000.0</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 100px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">SI</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 105px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 105px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">+Info</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="v-table-row" style="">
                     <td style="width: 325px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 325px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">Seguro de protección familiar plus</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 94px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 94px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">No</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 87px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 87px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">No</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 99px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 99px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">18 - 64</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 190px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 190px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">100000.01 - 2666666.0</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 100px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 100px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">SI</div>
                     </td>
                     <td style="width: 105px;" class="v-table-cell-content">
                        <div style="text-align: left; width: 105px;" class="v-table-cell-wrapper">+Info</div>
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </tbody>
            </table>
            <div style="height: 0px;" class="v-table-row-spacer"></div>
         </div>
         <div tabindex="0" style="position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div aria-hidden="true" style="display: none; width: 710px;" class="v-table-footer-wrap">
         <div class="v-table-footer" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div style="width: 900000px;">
               <table>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td style="width: 325px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 324px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 94px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 93px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 87px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 86px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 99px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 98px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 190px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 189px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 100px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 99px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 105px;">
                           <div class="v-table-footer-container" style="width: 104px;">&nbsp;</div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us? Like the CSS that sets the size and maybe a screenshot if not an actual link?

Comment: Hi! This is the HTML code generated in Vaadin and the CSS is so Big because is a Mixin with Liferay and Vaadin SCSS:

Comment: Hi! This is the HTML code generated in Vaadin :<div style="width: This is the fisrt column of the heather:<td style="width: 326px;" class="v-table-header-cell">
                           <div class="v-table-resizer"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-sort-indicator"></div>
                           <div class="v-table-caption-container v-table-caption-container-align-left" style="width: 317px;">Nombre del seguro</div>
                        </td>